# Why did the Japanese guy have this in his hands in The Wailing?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wailing

In the Korean movie The Wailing, the Japanese guy has the mark of a nail on his palm in the end. He shows it when in the cave. Much like a crucifixion. But he's shown to be the Devil.

What is the nail mark on his palm supposed to represent?